# Why is my region in my Neovim Syntax file unresponsive?

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-syntax-highlighting

First of all I'm using Neovim(v0.8.1) so I don't know if it also applies to Vim.

I'm creating a syntax file with the following region :

```
syn region TestRegion start='^RegionStart\n^NextLineStart' end='^RegionEnd'
hi TestRegion guifg=Red
```

I write the following :

```
RegionStart
NextLineStart
placeholder
RegionEnd
```

When I "break" the pattern and delete the 'N' of "NextLineStart", the lines stay highlighted. If I go to the end of the document then come back or reset the syntax (`:set syn=MySyntax`) it is not highlighted anymore.
Then if I reinsert the 'N' it doesn't highlight the region until I make the same manipulation.

On the other hand it reacts immediately when I modify "RegionStart" or "RegionEnd" either by entering or breaking the pattern.

What's stranger to me is that if I delete the 'S' of "NextLineStart" it does not react but if I do my little manipulation to make it not highlighted then reinsert the 'S' in its place it immediatly highlights the region.

Am I doing something wrong ? If not is there a way around it ?

Comment: Well your sample [works perfectly](https://i.imgur.com/dlaIAn6.png) in Vim 9.0.1276. Is there ore to your syntax script than your sample?

Comment: Not really, some ```if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

syntax clear
``` at the beggining then ```let b:current_syntax = "MySyntax"``` at the end. (To be honest I just deleted everything else (was already commented) to be sure just now)